# Is a connected, first countable space necessarily Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

Is a connected, first countable space necessarily Hausdorff?

I've been trying for forever to come up with a counterexample but haven't had any luck.

Comment: We do not remove questions just because they have been answered. To show that you are satisfied with an answer, click the checkmark next to the answer you are accepting.

Comment: [Trivial Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology)

Answer (score 3):

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org), an online version of the General Reference Chart from Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*, gives the following examples of connected, first countable spaces that are not Hausdorff. You can view the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Connected%2BFirst%20Countable%2B%7E%24T_2%24) to learn more about these spaces.

Compact Complement Topology

Countable Excluded Point Topology

Countable Particular Point Topology

Divisor Topology

Finite Complement Topology on a Countable Space

Finite Excluded Point Topology

Finite Particular Point Topology

Interlocking Interval Topology

Nested Interval Topology

Overlapping Interval Topology

Prime Ideal Topology

Right Order Topology on R

Sierpinski Space

Telophase Topology

Uncountable Excluded Point Topology

Uncountable Particular Point Topology

Answer (score 0):

Another example: the cofinite topology on the integers is $T_1$, second countable (so first countable), connected and very non-Hausdorff for the same reason: all non-empty open sets intersect.